# How to send ETRN from Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013

We have an external secondary MX which tries to deliver mail to the primary MX (exchange 2013) with a sliding scale schedule, which goes from 5 minutes all the way to a week. It happened that our server was down for more than 24 hours during the weekend and the messages held by the secondary MX waited there for several days before being delivered, although the server was back up.

As the secondary MX supports the ETRN command to trigger a delivery attempt, is there a way to issue that command upon Exchange's startup (or any other time)?

Comment: What is the external secondary MX?  There might be a command you can issue to tell it to retry delivery of everything in queue, but you didn't state what the system is.

Comment: Maybe I'm naïve, but I've never been a fan of the idea of having a secondary MX for this purpose. Sending servers are required to queue and retry later upon failing to establish a connection to your server, so why not let them?

Comment: @TheCleaner- I don't know what it's running on (www.rollernet.us). I just know it supports the ETRN command, hence this question about how to send it!

Comment: @joeqwerty- Because as written above, it might take a very long time to do so and knowing the queue can be release with a command, I'd like to speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

yes, basically you can initiate the ETRN command via telnet to the secondary MX and specify the domain for which to unqueue the mails. I belive the syntax (after opening a telnet-connection to port 25 of the secondary MX) is ETRN

you can try this in telnet.

Comment: You didn't explain how to trigger it on startup. That's what the question was asking about.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on how to trigger this at least periodically?